# Exception while running in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to do unit test for `JSONException`. Below it's the code:

```
public void testException(JSONObject jsonObj){
    try{
        String test = jsonObj.getString("test");
    }catch(JSONException e){
   }
}
```

But in the Unit tests when I give the below it throws a different exception:

```
@Test (expected=JSONException.class){
    mymockClass.testException(jsonObj);
}

java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: You're swallowing the exception, so it's not being propagated to the junit runner...

Comment: How do i test this case ? @ernest_k

Comment: You just dont catch exception and you let it be thrown up.

Comment: If you're testing the exception scenario, don't catch the exception. Or remove the `expected` exception to test that *errors raised by json tools don't get propagated* (but it's a bad practice to swallow exceptions just like that)

Answer (score 1):

Its because test expects that exception will be actually thrown out of test method, but you are catching it - thats why you have "expected exception has not been thrown" exception. Remove `try-catch` block and add `throws` to method signature.

```
public void testException(JSONObject jsonObj) throws JSONException{
        String test = jsonObj.getString("test");
}
```